# What is status-deferred?

Tags: support, tags, meta

Have there been any statements on the meaning of this tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work)

Comment: Ooo, a meta-Meta question!

Comment: Time to open a new website..

Answer (score 21):

It's a step up from Status-By-Design.

- Status Non Repro: *Problem? What Problem?*
- Status By Design: *That's not a bug, that's a feature*
- Status Deferred: *We recognize there's a problem. Hopefully if we leave it alone long enough it will go away*

Answer (score 5):

If it's used the same way here as we use it at my workplace, it means "yeah we'll totally get to that... *resume surfing stackoverflow*"

Answer (score 2):

On the per-site Metas of two sites that I moderate the tag wikis say:

> Indicates that the issue will be reviewed in the future, or that a
>   change in functionality is being delayed until a future date.

I interpret and use this status in at least two situations:

1. To indicate that resolution needs more work to be done on something else *within* our site before it can be implemented e.g. perhaps we are struggling to gain consensus on making two frequently used tags (each with their advocates) into synonyms.
2. To indicate that resolution needs more work to be done on something else *outside* of our site before it can be implemented e.g. perhaps a feature request has been made which needs to be implemented network-wide before it becomes available to our site.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/status-deferred/We'll get to it in 6-8 weeks./g
```

Comment: How do you read that? What language? stet?

Comment: That was pseudo-vim regexes...the only ones I do on a semi-never basis.

Comment: `vim`? *whoosh*

Comment: Deleting out of pure shame.

Comment: @random, it's [the essential command of `sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1)