# False negatives when validating notification e-mails ("widespread sloppy coding establishes a [stricter] de facto standard than the formal standard")

Tags: bug, status-deferred, notifications, email

**TL;DR: Stack Overflow's (and Stack Exchange's) client-side *and* server-side code rejects valid e-mail addresses**, this should be fixed: preferably by only making **a basic check, e.g. `^[^@]+@[^.]+(\.[^.]+)+$`** (as e-mail address validation with JS is an exercise in futility).

Stack Exchange is the network that tries to

> Make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions;

yet, for all the excellent Q&A we have on [e-mail address validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/201378#201378), I was horrified when a user [uncovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074652/email-validation-in-javascript) that this site itself uses a horrible, terrible, no good e-mail "verification" regex:
`^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$`

That thing looked eerily familiar. Indeed, it is the *notorious* regex from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html - which "matches all valid e-mail addresses". Or so the author claims - as he immediately adds that "I consider everything not matched by this to be invalid"; I see that logic as *slightly* circular, although he does have valid points for choosing that pattern in his specific situation (e.g. "meh, this is just a simple website, why bother with three nines?" and "there's no perfect regex anyway"). Alas, due to the [Bathroom Wall Of Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/the-bathroom-wall-of-code.html) effect, this regex found its way into various collections of "useful regexes" and thence to SO. Unfortunately, it seems that the various regex snippet libraries only disclose the first part of [@Jan Goyvaerts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/about.html)' assertion ("matches all valid e-mail addresses"), without highlighting the tradeoffs and pitfalls of this snippet (which the author discusses in quite some depth [on the aforementioned page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)).

Now, there's a lot of discussion and controversy on "the right way to validate e-mail addresses", and I think e.g. [this question addresses the technical parts excellently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses); but on top of that, *amongst* my issues with *this* particular usage are:

- a small site somewhere on the Net can get away with "I'll just reject your e-mail address because **** you, it's my site, now go away already"; that is an **inappropriate** approach for Stack Exchange.
- the regex is **outdated** and **inaccurate**, what with the new(ish) IDNs and ancient outliers such as `.travel` and `.museum`.
- and worst of all, it gives a **bad**, you could even say hypocritical, **example**: "do as we tell you, not as we do" - it is rather awkward to explain to people that no, this is a bad way to validate e-mails, on the same site which uses that code - [see the comments under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074652/email-validation-in-javascript). Also, we're actively contributing to the Bathroom Wall of Code effect ("Can we make a search-and-replace on the entire Internet? ... Oh.").

Let me quote from [Validate an E-Mail Address with PHP, the Right Way](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585):

> There is some danger that common usage and widespread sloppy coding will establish a de facto standard for e-mail addresses that is more restrictive than the recorded formal standard.

Do we want to be seen as perpetrators (propagandists even, as this is a network of sites for *learning*) of such "sloppy coding"? Such false negatives when validating addresses are the e-mail's equivalent of "[all text is ISO-8859-1](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text.html)", IMNSHO.

So, I have three suggestions of variable insanity:

- If there is a need (or an urge) to validate e-mails in JavaScript, since this check is only done once in a while, and then only when notification checkbox changes state (if I understand this correctly), the full [ex-parrot regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) would be useful
- Should the SE team see this as overkill, I'd suggest making this a *sanity* check only - if it doesn't pass the (possibly too-strict) regex, ask user if xe *really* wishes to use that address, but don't prevent it.

Note that I wrote "If there's a need (or urge)": I don't think that it's possible to determine in JavaScript whether something *is* a valid e-mail address - it is possible to determine that something is *not* a valid e-mail address, but even well-formed e-mail addresses are not guaranteed to be valid: `piskvor@example.com` passes even the most restrictive tests, yet I doubt you would reach me there. JS e-mail address validation may have been easier in 1998 (without all those pesky newfangled 4+ letter TLDs and whatnot), but in 2011, it's an exercise in frustration and futility - in fact, I would even call it cargo cult programming: most people implement it because "must have JS e-mail validation, everyone else has it" - without any real benefits from what often becomes a misfeature.

- So, by @Pekka's suggestion, and [with the help of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation), **I propose only checking for `@`** (and possibly a 2nd+ level domain name, but then it gets complicated again with IDNs and whatnot), and leaving the rest to the mail transfer agents - after all, those implement a parser for what is and what isn't an e-mail address (one would hope).

---

**Edit**: Like using MD5 for security, the problem isn't getting magically better by ignoring it. Quite the contrary, it's getting worse: Apart from the parallel IDN gTLD program, [ICANN has recently (June 2011) announced golden-rule*, free-for-all gTLDs](http://www.icann.org/en/announcements/announcement-20jun11-en.htm). If you think that excluding `.travel` is good policy because who cares, will it take something like `.apple` getting registered? This is - as of now - only a possibility, but it's another nail into the `\.[a-z]{2,4}$`'s coffin.

*The *other* golden rule obviously, as the vanity gTLDs will be quite expensive.

---

**Edit 2**: Oh dear. Apparently the regex lives in SO/SF/SU/SE's server side code as well - [see the screenshot, complete with freehand circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhcMz.png). From this, I infer that there's another place in the code which assumes `\.[a-z]{2,4}$` is correct. This is getting kind of silly.

Comment: FWIW, the solution presented in that LinuxJournal article isn't actually up to spec -- the most up to date RFC is 5321, published in late 2008.  I'm a fan of [Dominic Sayers' work](http://blog.dominicsayers.com/2011/03/14/email-address-validation/), as [his library](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/) has a [huge test suite](http://isemail.info/_system/is_email/test/?all) for compliance.  Unfortunately it's also PHP and not too useful for SO directly.  (Edit: Whoa [someone ported it to C#](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/downloads/list)!)

Comment: @Charles: I'm not saying his is the One Regex To Rule Them All (and it's not a regex, on top of that); also the DNS checks that his proposed code does are unsuitable for a client-side check. I'm quoting his observation which sums up the state of affairs on what is and what is not *perceived* as a valid e-mail address. I'm proposing two solutions of varying insanity in the last paragraph.

Comment: Wow. The comments on that SO post are... let's just say "underwhelming"... but that is some good catch.

Comment: @Popular Demand: For such a reliable flamebait topic as "email validation regex", they are pretty tame (no Godwins as yet).

Comment: It was my fault, it *is* being used. Track XHR in Chrome Dev Tools and you'll see that it isn't sending an XHR for .museum addresses, whereas it is sending an XHR for .com etc.

Comment: Isn't E-Mail validation beyond `*@*` silly anyway? What is it good for in the first place? I've never really understood that, and can't see any arguments for it e.g. here - [How far should one take e-mail address validation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3232)

Comment: @Pekka: Now, I've noticed a tendency for this programme to get rather silly. Yours is IMNSHO a very reasonable suggestion, edited to add that.

Comment: For a site that went with OpenID as "the right way to do things" I'm surprised they implemented such a shortsighted email verification routine.

Comment: [Here’s a properly validating RFC 5322 regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764247/why-are-regular-expressions-so-controversial/4053506#4053506)

Comment: @voter-to-close-as-OT: "Questions on Meta Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to the Stack Overflow family of websites and/or community in some way" - how does "**SE's** Javascript logic is broken" *not* relate to Stack Overflow, given that it's broken on all sites of the **S** tack **E** xchange network? *[mind boggles]*

Comment: Surely an email validator _could_ legitimately reject addresses at reserved domains, like "jack@example.com"? Although I emphatically, emphatically agree that this is one of the many, many cases that are not worth trying to filter out.

Comment: @Jack V.: Doing that in JS is kind of pointless - such whitelist would catch what, ten invalid domain names? Thirty? It will still let through `kaegkljklgioagioui@jkaseguiuiargjha.weiorhasper.guieprgeas.sdgkaeguiwssdhusd.com`,which is invalid (but good luck checking that *in JavaScript* )

Comment: [Oh, wonderful.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18996/what-is-status-deferred/18999#18999) *[gets all Righteously Offended and goes to sulk in the corner: They won't fix my bu-u-u-ug **now**, aa-a-and it's my faaa-aavorite oooo-o-one!]* ;o)

Comment: @Charles: [Phalanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanger_%28compiler%29)?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail, what about it?  The C# port of is_email is an independent work, not relying on Phalanger.  is_email also doesn't seem to have been updated since my comment two years ago, which is a bit sad.

Answer (score 21):

```
I wouldn't hesitate to use the full ex-parrot regex
```

I disagree. [This is a regex that matches ALL valid email addresses](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) but as you can see it's almost comical. *Regexps are not the right tool for this*.

I think there are two much better solutions:

- Do it right with an old fashioned parser.
- Don't do it at all. Don't go beyond checking if the email has a '@'. If someone wants to give you a fake email *they will* and there is *nothing* you can do about it. Just think of sites like [mailinator](http://www.mailinator.com/).

I believe the second solution is better: no dev time wasted, less error prone (compare the difficulty of implementing a parser based on an RFC to checking if there is a '@'), less annoying for people using fake email addresses (which again they will if they want to), and doesn't try to solve a problem that can't be solved through validation checks.

Comment: Well, you are right that this is not a good use for regexes; IMNSHO, it's not a good use for *anything* - JS e-mail validation is mostly a cargo-cult exercise left over from the 1990s (when it may have served a useful purpose). Edited.

Comment: My eyes.. MY EYES ...

Comment: [This regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764247/why-are-regular-expressions-so-controversial/4053506#4053506) validates RFC 5322 addresses.